# Doing math on a Bash function and declaring it into a variable in 1 line

Tags: bash

I'd like to do a file rowcount and subtract one from it. I know how to do the first part of getting the rowcount with this function:

```
zcat filename$today.csv.gz | wc -l
```

But how do I subtract one from that value to account for headers and store it in a variable? I've tried

```
$(( zcat filename$today.csv.gz | wc -l - 1 ))
```

but that isn't working.

Do I have to store the first function's output as a variable first? Is that the recommended practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one-liner can do the job:

```
n=$(( $(zcat filename$today.csv.gz  | wc -l) - 1 ))
```